# writing in the air with python and opencv

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

i just wondering, is there any tutorial about "writing in the air from webcam using python and opencv"? I mean using hand gesture to write and recognize the letter we write

Comment: I don't know if there is the tutorial, but you can just detect the hand (open for example) and track its movement by let's say background extraction. Later, the task becomes OCR...

Comment: Hi marol, do you have the tutorial about that?if possible i hope it with source code. cuz as long as i search in the net it's only show video without a source code.

Comment: First - I don't have and second- I was only suggesting that you can do that without tutorial, if you compose the system you want from three pieces: hand detection, hand tracking (e.g. with background extraction) and finally do the OCR. I'm pretty sure you can find tutorials to this three pieces...